# view events are set twice when I instantiate view second time

Tags: requirejs

This is my project architecture issue - its my first backbone project and I probably did something wrong.

In all my project in route callbacks I have:

```
myroute: function() {
    this.currentView = new MyCustomView();
},

mysecondroute: function() {
    this.currentView = new MySecondView()
},
//...
```

So in all route callbacks I instantiate some view. This view has initialze method which calls render method. It works except that all view events (declared in `events: {}`) are 'binded' every time same view is instantiated. so when I visit same route twice events for view corresponding to this route are fired twice...

Probably I shouldn instantiate new view on every route call - but how I can do this ? I mean what are the standards? Maybe I should just unload current view somehow - is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a method to unbind all the events at the time to close the view

like this

```
close : function () {
   //your code to clean everything before closing the view
   this.remove();
   this.unbind();
}
```

so the next time the view is called the events will be added during the initialization of the view, thats why you had events being called twice. the initialize method binds the events to the .el element. you need to make sure you unbind those at some point.